# java: How to randomly show output

Tags: java, java-me

I have two messages "Job 1 " and "Job 2". I want to put these messages into loop and every time when it executes it randomly display output: like

```
Job1
job2
job2
job1
and so on..
```

Comment: Define "randomly" - it's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  Do you want the jobs to execute in a random order?  When Job1 executes should it always print "job1" or can it print "job2" as well?  Does each pair of lines contain both jobs in arbitrary order, or is `job2 job2 job2 job2 job2` valid output?

Comment: yes, the order should be random. like whenever any job executes it should display the message either "JOb1" or "Job2".

Comment: You've glossed over an important point - should each loop iteration execute *both jobs* with an arbitrary one being first, or should it execute *one arbitrary job*?  You example output and your description are both consistent with either methodology.

Comment: what does this has to do with java ME? are you developing a MIDlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Random class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Put them in a list and then say:

```
for(i = 0; i < howeverManyTimesYouWantToLoop; i++) {
  System.out.println(jobList.get(new Random().nextInt(jobList.size()));
}
```